# I am having an issue with a stack overflow on a problem

Tags: javascript

this is from a Hackerrank takehome.  I am trying to figure out why the time complexity is

I've gone through line by line testing what the expected input and output should be and it passes but for some reason I'm passing the time constraint on all the test cases and

```
// let input = [
//     'mission statement',
//     'a quick bite to eat',
//     'a chip off the old block',
//     'chocolate bar',
//     'mission impossible',
//     'a man on a mission',
//     'block party',
//     'eat my words',
//     'bar of soap'
// ];

// expected output = [
//     'a quick bite to eat my words',
//     'a chip off the old block party',
//     'chocolate bar of soap',
//     'a man on a mission statement',  
//     'a man on a mission impossible'
// ]



function generate_phrases(phrases) {
    //instantiate result = []
    const result = [];
    //iterate through input phrases
    for(let i = 0; i < phrases.length; i++){
      //subarray1 of each phrase split(' ');
      let sub1 = phrases[i].split(' ');
     //inner loop through phrases
      for(let j = 0; j < phrases.length; i++){
        //create subarray2
        let sub2 = phrases[j].split(' ');
        //if last element in subarray1 === first element in subarray 2
        if(sub1[sub1.length-1] === sub2[0]){
          //combine and join the arrays into string 
          let string = sub1.concat(sub2.slice(1)).join(' ');
          //push string to result array
          result.push(string);
        }
      }
    }
  return result;
}
```

python tutor gives "Error: stopped after running 1000 steps and cannot display visualization.
Shorten your code, since Python Tutor is not designed to handle long-running code."

Repl got caught up on it, not sure where the overflow is happening.
I know my time complexity could probably be better, i'm just not seeing why the iterative solution is taking so many steps, even when I shorten the input two two string that should concat, as in

```
let input = [
    'mission impossible',
    'a man on a mission', 
];
```

still surpasses the time limit

Comment: This is O(n²) and can be O(n)

Comment: change `for(let j = 0; j < phrases.length; i++){` to `for(let j = 0; j < phrases.length; j++){`

Comment: omg, how silly.  well, i guess I didn't pass the test...  thanks anyways!

Comment: @JonasWilms [I've tried](https://jsfiddle.net/x9qmhjsL/) and really wonder how to achieve a O(n). It's not O(n²) but it's not O(n) either. Can you please explain how to achieve O(n)? What I've tried is in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/x9qmhjsL/